# Multiple structure pointers inside another structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing code to create a team of players

```
struct player {
  char name[32];
  double avg;
};

struct team {
  char teamname[32];
  player *players[11];
};
```

I get the error:
A4.c:31:3: error: unknown type name ‘player’
   player *players[11];

I've looked elsewhere on the internet and I can't seem to find out how I would store multiple player pointers inside the team structure?

Comment: `player` isn't a type name, it's a `struct` name.  So you need to use `struct player` in the reference inside of `team`.

Comment: You need to use `struct player` instead of just `player`. Or declare player with typedef

Answer (score 2):

```
struct player {
  char name[32];
  double avg;
};
```

In the above code, player is a struct name, not a type. So the correct definition of `team` is:

```
struct team {
  char teamname[32];
  struct player *players[11];
};
```

Alternatively, you can define a new player type:

```
typedef struct player {
  char name[32];
  double avg;
} player;

struct team {
  char teamname[32];
  player *players[11];
};
```

Note: In C++, the struct keyword is optional before in declaration of a variable. In C, it is mandatory. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structures-in-cpp/)

Comment: You might mention that this is a C++ habit. C doesn't have implicit names for structures.